# Visual studio 2015 xlocnum C++ issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual studio version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. While upgrading an existing project in C++ from VS2k13 to VS2k15, I am getting the following build errors in xlocnum file placed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum.

```
Error C2912 explicit specialization 'void std::numpunct<char>::_Getvals(void)' is not a specialization of a function template   Scripttest C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum   192

and
```

Error C2061 syntax error: identifier '_Elem2'   InterPTest  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum  188.

Following code in xlocnum is throwing the error

```
template<_Elem2>
        void _Getvals(_Elem2, const lconv *_Ptr, _Locinfo::_Cvtvec _Cvt)
        {   // get values
        _Dp = _MAKLOCCHR(_Elem2, _Ptr->decimal_point[0], _Cvt);
        _Kseparator = _MAKLOCCHR(_Elem2, _Ptr->thousands_sep[0], _Cvt);
        }
```

After explicitly typenameing template<_Elem2> with template, error resolves but the change has to be made in the windows file xlocnum itself, so its doesn't seem a valid solution. Please suggest a resolution for this issue, Thanks

Comment: In my copy of the exact same version it says `template<class _Elem2>`.

Comment: Thanks Bo, this has helped to resolve the issue